# java.sql.Statement.executeQuery(String sql) throws SQLException when DELETE sql query is used

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, eclipse-rcp

I know that to execute sql DELETE statement, I need to use executeUpdate(). However my need is to support only SELECT statment, hence I am using executeQuery(String sql).
My db is Oracle.

My problem is, I am using java.sql.Statement.executeQuery(String sql) in a desktop based application, a textbox in our app accepts any kind of query and while testing we found that executeQuery(sql) is actually executing a DELETE query, i.e it is successfully deleting a record and then throwing error -SQLException.

1. Shouldn't the api not allow DELETE query to be executed ?.
2. What can be done to prevent DELETE query to be executed by Statement.executeQuery api ?

Comment: Perhaps you can change db privileges to revoke all privileges except from select priv from the db user  you are connecting as through jdbc. Is this possible? (i.e. do you have a specific db user which is not owner of these objects?)

Comment: Also what SQLexception are you getting (I'm curious because I can't imaging delete is succesful but throws exception anyway)

Comment: Mina, Our textbox is a multiline free textbox to accept anything, validating my textbox is a last thing i want to take up. But the api 'executeQuery(sql)' returns a 'ResultSet', meaning it should accept only SELECT. Because executeQuery(sql) executes the query and when we do this check resultSet.getMetaData() throws SQLException

Comment: Mina, I tried to use setReadOnly(true); on the Connection object: docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/… However, issue still persists

Comment: I was just suggesting you to manage these privs from database site (not to make validation on textbox). Like that frontend client is connecting to database as some database user and to revoke dml privileges from that user.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to explicitely manage not execute INSERT, UPDATE & DELETE queries through executeQuery() method. This is as per the JDBC specification so it will accept delete queries as well and will throw an exception.

```
executeQuery() is used for SELECT sql operation
executeUpdate() is used for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE sql operation.
```

your query is for DELETE operation thus please use stmt.executeUpdate();

As you mentioned the you are getting this from a textbox form user, You can add the validations on the query string itself before executing it.

Lets say you get the query in String, you can check if string starts with SELECT then only execute.

```
if (StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCaseAndWs(sql, "INSERT") 
                    || StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCaseAndWs(sql, "UPDATE") 
                    || StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCaseAndWs(sql, "DELETE") 
                    || StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCaseAndWs(sql, "DROP") 
                    || StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCaseAndWs(sql, "CREATE") 
                    || StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCaseAndWs(sql, "ALTER")
                    || StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCaseAndWs(sql, "TRUNCATE")) { 

                    // Return message Unable to execute any update or modification queries through executeQuery()
        } else {
        //Execute Query 
}
```

Comment: abhijeet, i know that executeUpdate needs to be used for DELETE sql operation, my problem is i am using executeQuery as I intend to support only SELECT operation. However the textbox in our app accepts any kind of query, and when DELETE is used, executeQuery simply executes it successfully and then throws exception. 

Are u getting my issue now ?

Comment: As you mentioned the you are getting this from a textbox form user, You can add the validations on the query string itself before executing it.

Lets say you get the query in String, you can check if string starts with SELECT then only execute.

Comment: Our textbox is a multiline free textbox to accept anything.

Comment: can you please post the code for your textbox. How you are reading the value of textbox?

Comment: Our textbox is a multiline free textbox to accept anything, validating my textbox is a last thing i want to take up. But the api 'executeQuery(sql)' returns a 'ResultSet', meaning it should accept only SELECT. Because executeQuery(sql) executes the query and when we do this check resultSet.getMetaData() throws SQLException

Comment: There is no direct option available to avoid it. You can do one thing, you can catch the SQLException and rollback executed operation over there.

Comment: I tried to use setReadOnly(true); on the Connection object:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setReadOnly(boolean)

However, issue still persists